# How to write to an already completed PDF file, using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

[image: My PDF]I have a PDF file that I would like to add text or numbers to specific positions. The PDF has boxes and I want to put the text in specific boxes. I use iText and Java.

I do this, but i have to hard-code the x and y of my text. I want to know how to find the position of my paragrafs then put the text under there.

```
lPdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(1);
  ColumnText ct = new ColumnText( content );
  ct.setSimpleColumn(200,549,500,10);
  ct.setText(new Phrase("4"));
  ct.go();
```

Under the month days in my pdf image, i want to write something, numbers or text.

It would be great if someone could tell me how to do that.

Comment: How do you expect to recognize the paragraphs under which to put your text? Is there enough free space under those paragraphs?

Comment: Using AcroForm fields is the standard way to define the rectangles in a PDF template.

Comment: mkl - I dont' know how this kan be fixed. I expect that it might somehow read the structure of my completed PDF file and then be able to find the positions of my paragraphs, but I can only speculate. I think that there is enough space there. I can not send photo here, I do not have enough reputation

Comment: Bruno ,  I'll check your advice, thanks

Comment: Do I interpret your image correctly assuming that you want to fill text into the "table cells"? (I put that in quotes because most likely the PDF there only has some lines and no knowledge of some table structure.)

Comment: Yes, you interpret the image correctly. Do you mean that, with itext it is not possible to "scan" the table structure? if true, how can i hard-code the position of my text in the best way, so I don't need to add a column just because i want to add some text ( ct.setSimpleColumn(200,549,500,10 ))

Answer (score 0):

Now i have one solution. I can save my existing pdf to a document and than add some text to it, but the existing pdf is two pages long and i can "scan" only the first page. How can i "scan" both pages of my original pdf to a document?

Here is my code

```
package pdfmodifier;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 *
 * @author Xdeveloper
 */
public class PDFmodifier {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    try {

//create pdf output
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\monthreport-Stamped.pdf"));
document.open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

//load existing pdf
InputStream templateInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\monthreport.pdf");
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templateInputStream);
PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
//PdfImportedPage page2 = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 2);

//copy first page of my existing pdf
document.newPage();
cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
cb.beginText();
BaseFont f_cn = BaseFont.createFont("C:\\calibri.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
cb.setFontAndSize(f_cn, 12);

//Namn
cb.setTextMatrix(59, 652);  //(xPos, yPos)
String ok = "Patrik Andersson";
cb.showText(ok);

//År
cb.setTextMatrix(257, 712);  //(xPos, yPos)
String year = "2015";
cb.showText(year); 

cb.endText();
//cb.addTemplate(page2, 0, 0);

document.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Ok, now i can copy both pages from an existing pdf to a new destination pdf. I think, i have what i need.

```
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
System.out.println(n);
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    document.newPage();
    page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
    cb.addTemplate(page, 0, i);
 }
```

---

```
package pdfmodifier;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 *
 * author Xdeveloper
 */
public class PDFmodifier {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    static PdfImportedPage page;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        //create output
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\monthreport-Stamped.pdf"));
document.open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

//load existing pdf
InputStream templateInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\monthreport.pdf");
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templateInputStream);
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
System.out.println(n);
//copy both pages of my existing pdf to new destination pdf
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            document.newPage();
            page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
            cb.addTemplate(page, 0, i);
        }

cb.beginText();
BaseFont f_cn = BaseFont.createFont("C:\\calibri.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252,  BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
cb.setFontAndSize(f_cn, 12);

//Namn
cb.setTextMatrix(59, 652); //Add text (x-position, y-position)
String ok = "Patrik Andersson";
cb.showText(ok);

//År
cb.setTextMatrix(257, 707);
String year = "2015";
cb.showText(year); 

cb.endText();

document.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```